# How can I apply TrackballControls to a moving target?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to apply the three.js script TrackballControls to a moving object in a way that preserves the ability to zoom and rotate the camera while the object moves through the scene. For example, I would like to be able to have the camera "follow" a moving planet, while the user retains the ability to zoom and rotate around the planet. Here is a basic jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mareid/8egUM/3/

(The mouse control doesn't actually work on jsfiddle for some reason, but it does on my machine).

I would like to be able to attach the camera to the red sphere so that it moves along with it, but **without losing the ability to zoom and rotate**. I can get the camera to follow the sphere easily enough by adding lines like these to the render() function:

```
mouseControls.target = new THREE.Vector3(object.position);
camera.position.set(object.position.x,object.position.y,object.position.z+20);
```

But if I do that, the fixed camera.position line overrides the ability of TrackballControls to zoom, rotate, etc. Mathematically, I feel like it should be possible to shift the origin of all of the TrackballControls calculations to the centre of the red sphere, but I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried all sorts of vector additions of the position of the red sphere to the _this.target and _eye vectors in TrackballControls.js, to no avail.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend `OrbitControls` rather than `TrackballControls`. My answer here applies primarily to `OrbitControls`; the same principle might also work with `TrackballControls` (I have not looked at its code in a while).

If you look at how `OrbitControls` works you should notice it uses `this.object` for the camera, and `this.target` for where the camera is looking at, and it uses that vector (the difference between them) for some of its calculations. Movement is applied to both positions when panning; only the camera is moved when rotating. `this.pan` is set to shift the camera, but out of the box it only deals with a panning perpendicular to the `this.object` to `this.target` vector because of the way it sets the panning vector.

Anyway, if you subtract the vector from `object.position` to `controls.target` and set `controls.pan` to that vector, that should make it jump to that object:

**Fixed example code:**

Add a helper to `OrbitControls.js` which has access to its local `pan` variable:

```
function goTo( vector ) {
    // Cloning given vector since it would be modified otherwise
    pan.add( vector.clone().sub( this.target ) );
}
```

Your own code:

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mouseControls.goTo( object.position ); // Call the new helper
    mouseControls.update();
    render();

}
```

You'll also probably want to set `mouseControls.noPan` to true.

Comment: Thanks, @Leeft.  I have tried OrbitControls, but it doesn't seem to work in any context. No matter where I try it, I get errors on lines 114 and 293. This example shows the problem: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ubEBr). The console in Firefox shows the error as "TypeError: (intermediate value).setFromUnitVectors is not a function" for line 114 and "lastQuaternion.dot is not a function" for line 293. One or the other always comes up for me in every implementation and in every browswer. Can you help?

Comment: I dredged up someone's old copy of OrbitControls.js ([link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3587259/Code/Threejs/OrbitControls.js)) and it seems to work. The problem with the current release--the one I'd prefer to use--seems to lie with some bug in THREE.Quaternion's methods, which are pretty opaque to me.

Comment: Updated your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wvenx ... newer three.js r.68, you were using the current OrbitControls.js with an old .r60 three.js ... that's the only change I had to make.

Comment: Thanks, @Leeft. Your method worked. I just had to make two small corrections. To suit my example, I had to change `controls.Target` to `mouseControls.target`. Also, it looks like your example is trying to change the `pan` variable within the `OrbitControls` constructor but it's actually conflicting with the `pan` method in the same constructor. I just added a single line to `OrbitControls` to fix it: `this.myspecialpan = pan` and then changed the code to `mouseControls.myspecialpan.add`.  It works.  Here is the codepen for those who are interested: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGBst)

Comment: Ah yes, of course ... I've added methods on my OrbitControls to help navigate the camera which abstract that away, I'll update my answer shortly. Nice that you got it sorted now though.

Comment: Thanks. I'd love to see some of your examples using `OrbitControls`. The library is much, much easier to understand than `TrackballControls`, but I find that the rotations controls in `OrbitControls` are poor. Dragging up and down rotates left and right (and vice versa) and you can't rotate all the way around an object. I'm futzing with it to get it the way I need it, but if you have good examples of customized versions, I'd love to see them. `TrackballControls` does all of this so nicely.

Comment: Well this is turning into a discussion which doesn't belong here, but if you look at my profile my current project is listed there, and has a github link. For my map, TrackballControls wasn't usable and goes mad at a top down view because TC uses Euler, OC uses quaternions. I modified OC to keep the panning on a fixed X-Z plane, which helps the map navigation greatly. A FSM for more control, Tween for smooth rotations ... and due another refactor.